# How to debug Kubernetes CreateContainerConfigError

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to learn configuring Kubernetes and am currently studying configuring pods with configmaps.

I just created a simple pod with nginx, trying to link it to a configmap called options with the following yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: pod
  name: pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: pod
    resources: {}
    env:
      - name: options
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: option
            key: var5
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

When looking at my pods, I see a `CreateContainerConfigError` error. My question is:
How can you debug a pod that has a config error? I am not interested in what went wrong in this specific case, is it possible to, for example, go into the pod and see what was wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Run `kubectl describe pod <podname> -n <namespace>`, you might see the cause of failing.

If pod not started then you can not exec into pod, In this case run `kubectl get pods -o wide` and check in which node the pod is scheduled. Go to that node and run `docker ps -a` and get the container id desired container. then check `docker logs -f <container id>`

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I thought I'd have to find a way to sh into the container, but the `describe` command perfectly displays all relevant events (and in this case therefore erros, a typo in my configmap)

Comment: Could you please describe the steps for "go to that node" and checking the logs for a specific container id?

Comment: you can ssh into the node. @CubeJockey